# How to add all nearby POI in mapbox?

Tags: ios, swift, database, mapbox

I am using MapBox and want to show the user all nearby Gym's/Fitness Clubs when the view appears. I cannot find any documentation on this on their website.

I do not have my own dataset to upload and dont want to add all locations in myself, is there an existing database i can query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show gyms/fitness centers specifically on a Mapbox map, you will most likely need to add your own data. For more information about data that you can extract from Mapbox vector tiles, please see the [Mapbox Streets v8 guide](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/mapbox-streets-v7/).

You could incorporate gyms from a third-party API as a symbol layer, then hide other POIs in your map. One way to do this is to create a custom map style in [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/) that includes your data.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a different map service you would recommend i use or tutorial you know that i could follow to implement this?